# objective-c switch case with multiple arguments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Probably a basic question but I would like to reduce some code using multiple arguments on switch case statements. Possible? Correct syntax?

```
switch (myInteger){
            case (1):   //here I would like to apply multiple arguments as case (1 || 3 || 5)
                <#statements#>
                break;
            case (2):
                <#statements#>
                break;
            default:
                break;
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use multiple `case`s right below each other.

```
switch (myInteger) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
        // statements
        break;
    case 2:
        // statements
        break;
    default:
        // statements
        break;
}
```

Comment: it is one of the greatest improvements in SWIFT that you can write cases in the same line separated with commas.

Comment: So you are saying that if you put some code under case 5, it will run if case 1, 3 or 5 is selected?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Yes. This "feature" is called "fall-through". The path of execution finds the applicable case statement, and then executes whatever comes after it until it reaches a `break` statement.

Answer (score 14):

```
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
    statements;
    break;
case 2:
    statements;
    break;
default:
    break;
```

Comment: You have a a typo (no colon after the 5). And there is no need for the parentheses.

Comment: LOL, typing fast trying to beat the rush of correct answers... thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 4):

For **Swift 3** there is a modification that I would like to mention

```
switch some value to consider {
case 1: //single argument
  print("ABC")

case 2,3: // multiple arguments
  print("KLM")

default:
  print("XYZ")
}
```

Hope it helps you. Thanks

Comment: @Adrian scroll up for Objective C version :D

Comment: Need Objective - C version

Answer (score -1):

Switch case must declare inside the main method

SYNTAX

```
Switch (variable r expression)
{ 
   Case 1 : 
     Body ; 
   Break

   Case 2 :
     Body;
   Break;

   Default :
     Body ;
   Break;
}
```

Comment: That is a syntax for switch case in easy mode